# Как выбрать правильные причастия в этих предложениях?

Tags: прилагательные, причастия

У меня есть дилемма. Скажите, как выбрать правильные причастия в этих предложениях?

1. Пример силы - сила тяжести, (действующая, действующей) на любое тело у поверхности земли.
2. Круг есть часть плоскости, (лежащая, лежащей) внутри окружности.
3. формы движения, (изучаемые, изучаемого) в кинематике.
4. детали машин, (изготовляемые, изготовляемых) из алюминия.
5. свойства соединений, (используемые, используемых) как окислители в лаборатории.

Мой ответ: 1. действующая 2. лежащая 3. изучаемого 4. изготовляемые 5. используемых. Не знаю, верно или нет.

Answer (score 0):

В этом задании нужно определить слово, от которого зависит причастие, и согласовать последнее.
Ваши ответы верны.

Comment: Третий ответ неверен. Там согласование должно быть по *формы*, то есть *изучаемые*.

Comment: @Nektoid, мне кажется, здесь можно сказать, что кинематика изучает и формы движения, и движение.

Comment: Кинематика изучает движение вообще, поэтому не требуется уточнения: формы, мол, именно того движения, которое изучается в кинематике.